# Rails can't access uploaded file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, upload

I searched the internet for hours trying to make this work, i didn't had any luck.

I upload a file and try to write it to the public/uploads directory (which already exists)

```
name = archivo.original_filename
directory = "public/uploads"
path = File.join(directory, name)
Dir.mkdir(directory) unless File.directory?(directory)
File.open(path, "wb") { |f| f.write(archivo.read) }
```

And i get the exception

```
No such file or directory - public/uploads/SERVITEST.xls
```

I tried using the absolute path and read the file from the /tmp directory with no luck, I got this Exception:

```
Permission denied - oo_7598_6341257208
```

I really don't know what is happening, since in every example for file upload i saw the controller could see the public directory

thanks in advance

greetings

SOLUTION:

After a good night of sleep and a couple of coffe cups, I solved the "No such file or directory" issue with the following:

```
directory = Rails.root.join("public","uploads");
```

And the "Permission denied" issue was a problem with the roo gem, since it was trying to access a undefined ROO_TMP environment variable:

```
export ROO_TMP=/tmp
```

Thanks to everyone for your help :D

Comment: On your machine or in production?  Sounds like you don't have write access to that directory from whatever user you are running the rails app with.

Comment: On my local machine, running with Webrick

Comment: Qué tal Jose. What is the permissions on that directory?

Comment: The Webrick server is running with the user owner of the folders, plus the folders have 0777 permissions